# Why does 33791st prime (399137) cause Segmentation Fault?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, dynamic-memory-allocation

So obviously the number 399137 in and of its self doesn't cause a segmentation fault, but my program consistently crashes on the same computation. It calculates the values of Euler's totient ([phi function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function)) from 2 to a given limit (default 1,000,000). It does so by keeping a linearly ordered list of primes from previously computed values of Euler's totient. When attempting to add the 33791st prime number (339137) to the list of primes it results in a segmentation fault. Note memory isn't realloc'd on this computation. I tried using `gdb` to locate the problem and it pointed to the line where the the prime number is added to the list (see below).

To store all the primes below 1 million my program would dynamically allocate `8192*10*4` bytes `(320KB)`. Requiring that much contiguous memory doesn't seem problematic to me.

So why does the my program consistently have a segmentation fault when attempting to add 339137 to the list of primes? What is the cause of this segmentation fault?

**`C Code:`**

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

uint32_t phi       (uint32_t n, uint32_t *primes, uint32_t *count, uint32_t *size);
uint32_t gcd_bin   (uint32_t u, uint32_t v);
uint32_t isPrime   (uint32_t n, uint32_t *primes, uint32_t *count, uint32_t *size);
void     addPrime  (uint32_t n, uint32_t *primes, uint32_t *count, uint32_t *size);
uint32_t isInArr   (uint32_t n, uint32_t *primes, uint32_t count);
uint32_t expand_arr(uint32_t **arr, uint32_t *size);
void     print_arr (uint32_t  *arr, uint32_t count);
uint32_t print_help(char* str);

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  uint32_t z=1000000;         //default
  uint32_t count=0,size = 10; //default
  uint32_t i,n;
//  uint32_t x,y; //max numerator & denominator of ratio
  uint32_t *primes = malloc(size * sizeof(uint32_t));

  if(argc > 1 && !strcmp(argv[1],"--help")) { return print_help(argv[0]); }
  if(argc > 1) {  sscanf(argv[1],"%u",&z); }

  uint32_t old=size;
  for(i=2,/*x=y=1,*/count=0; i<=z; ++i) {
    n = phi(i,primes,&count,&size);
    fprintf(stderr,"\ni=%u phi(i)=%u\t: c=%u s=%u ",i,n,count,size);
  }
//  printf("%u/%u\n",x,y);
  return 0;
}

uint32_t phi(uint32_t n, uint32_t *primes, uint32_t *count, uint32_t *size) {
  uint32_t i,bound;
  // Base case
  if(n < 2)
    return 0;
  // Is Prime? (Lehmer's conjecture)
  if(isPrime(n,primes,count,size))
    return n-1;
  // Even number?
  if((n & 1) == 0 ) {
    int m = n >> 1;
    return ~m & 1 ? phi(m,primes,count,size)<<1 : phi(m,primes,count,size);
  }
  // Find (smallest) prime factor using list of primes
  for(i=0,bound=(uint32_t)sqrt(n); primes[i] < bound && i<*count && (n%primes[i])!=0; ++i);
  uint32_t m = primes[i];
  uint32_t o = n/m;
  uint32_t d = gcd_bin(m, o);
  return d==1 ? phi(m,primes,count,size)*phi(o,primes,count,size)
              : phi(m,primes,count,size)*phi(o,primes,count,size)*(d/phi(d,primes,count,size));
}

uint32_t isPrime(uint32_t n, uint32_t *primes, uint32_t *count, uint32_t *size) {
  uint32_t i,prime,bound;
  for(i=0,prime=1,bound=(uint32_t)sqrt(n)+1; prime && i<*count && primes[i]<=bound; ++i)
    prime = n%primes[i];
  if(prime)
    addPrime(n,primes,count,size);
  return prime;
}

void addPrime(uint32_t n, uint32_t *primes, uint32_t *count, uint32_t *size) {
  if(*count >= *size) {
    if(!expand_arr(&primes,size)) {
      fprintf(stderr,"dying gracefully!");
      exit(1); //realloc failure
    }
  }
  if(!isInArr(n,primes,*count))
    primes[(*count)++] = n; /* ERROR IS HERE APPARENTLY */
}

uint32_t expand_arr(uint32_t **primes, uint32_t *size) {
  *size  *= 2;
  *primes = realloc(*primes, *size * sizeof(uint32_t));
  return *primes!=NULL;
}

uint32_t isInArr(uint32_t n, uint32_t *primes, uint32_t count) {
  uint32_t hi,low,mid,val;
  low = 0; hi = count; // set bounds
  while(low < hi) {    // binary search
    mid = low/2 + hi/2;
    val = primes[mid];
    if(val == n) return  1;
    if(val >  n) hi  = mid;
    if(val <  n) low = mid+1;
  }
  return 0;
}

void print_arr(uint32_t *arr, uint32_t count) {
  uint32_t i;
  for(i=0; i<count; ++i)
    printf("%u,",arr[i]);
  printf("\n");
}

uint32_t gcd_bin(uint32_t u, uint32_t v) {
    /* simple cases (termination) */
    if(u == v)  return u;
    if(u == 0)  return v;
    if(v == 0)  return u;
    /* look for even numbers  */
    if( ~u & 1) {
      if(v & 1) return gcd_bin(u >> 1, v);           /* u is even, v is odd  */
      else      return gcd_bin(u >> 1, v >> 1) << 1; /* u is even, v is even */
    }
    if( ~v & 1) return gcd_bin(u, v >> 1);           /* u is odd,  v is even */
    /* reduce larger argument */                     /* u is odd,  v is odd  */
    return (u > v) ? gcd_bin((u - v) >> 1, v)
                   : gcd_bin((v - u) >> 1, u);
}

uint32_t print_help(char* str) {
  printf("  Usage: %s <limit> \n",str);
  printf("  Calculates the values of euler's totient (phi fnction) \n");
  printf("  from 2 to <limit> inclusively\n");
  printf("  * limit : a decimal number\n");
  printf("          : default = 1000000\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: tried starting "later" in the prime sequence, e.g. starting at 2 instead of 1, and see if the 33792nd prime causes the segfault then? If it does, then you've got a memory overrun error somewhere.

Comment: What would happen if you recoded this to pre-allocate your prime buffer one time to a size larger than where to crash is occurring.  It might help isolate the area to that portion of the code and make things simpler to manage.  I personally am not a fan of realloc schemes and would rather see a single buffer made big enough to hold all your primes, but I also understand there are times when it is necessary.

Comment: I'd suggest using `valgrind` to run your application. It shows 605 errors in 59 contexts. I think you've got something to chew on.

Comment: @MarcB I edited the primality test to include the following at the beginning: `if(~n & 1) return 0;` to skip 2 as a prime number. The program crashes when the count reaches 337991; trying to compute the 33792nd prime (399149).

Comment: Is this intentionally written to be overly complex? It seems quite complicated to me...

Comment: @BryanOlivier I ran `valgrind` and notice a lot of `invalid read`s, any suggestion on where the problem might be?

Comment: @MarcB and MichaelDorgan It's a shame the first two comments were guesswork. There are tools (thankyou, @BryanOlivier) that eliminate guesswork when debugging... @awashburn: `assert` seems like one tool that might be helpful, for you...

Comment: @awashburn Valgrind tells you where the problems are... Which manual are you reading?

Comment: @awashburn As a rule of thumb, you always want to fix the *very first* problem valgrind tells you about.  All subsequent errors are, at least potentially, what we call [secondary damage](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/S/secondary-damage.html) -- might not have happened if the initial error hadn't happened.

Comment: @awashburn At first glance it looks like you are accessing already freed memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, the best tool for finding a bug of this type is [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/).  Ignore all the options and just run it as `valgrind ./a.out`, then fix the *very first* problem it reports.  Repeat until program runs correctly.

Now, in this case the problem is apparent to me from code inspection because I know what to look for.  I *learned* what to look for by debugging a gazillion of these problems, with the aid of valgrind.  Valgrind is your friend.  Use it.

```
uint32_t expand_arr(uint32_t **arr, uint32_t *size);
```

This function expands the array pointed to by the pointer pointed to by the `arr` argument, overwriting the old pointer with the new one.

```
void addPrime(uint32_t n, uint32_t *primes, uint32_t *count, uint32_t *size) {
  if(*count >= *size) {
    if(!expand_arr(&primes,size)) {
```

This function invokes `expand_arr` on the `primes` pointer, which is a function parameter, and therefore a *copy* of the pointer known to the caller.  When `expand_arr` changes `primes`, that *only* affects the copy here in `addPrime`, *not* the copy in its caller; the caller's pointer is left pointing to freed memory.

In fact, `primes` is threaded as a function argument all the way back up through `isPrime` and `phi` to `main`.  All of those functions need to pass `primes` around as a pointer to a pointer, as `expand_arr` already does, so that no stale pointers are left behind when `expand_arr` calls `realloc`.

Here's how valgrind would have told you that this is the problem:

```
i=29 phi(i)=28  : c=10 s=10 ==17052== Invalid read of size 4
==17052==    at 0x4009D5: isPrime (test.c:59)
==17052==    by 0x400BC4: phi (test.c:41)
==17052==    by 0x400DCB: main (test.c:28)
==17052==  Address 0x54de040 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 40 free'd
==17052==    at 0x4C2C03E: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:662)
==17052==    by 0x4008C9: expand_arr (test.c:79)
==17052==    by 0x400968: addPrime (test.c:68)
==17052==    by 0x400A07: isPrime (test.c:62)
==17052==    by 0x400BC4: phi (test.c:41)
==17052==    by 0x400C50: phi (test.c:53)
==17052==    by 0x400DCB: main (test.c:28)
```

Notice how it's pointing you at `isPrime` as the location of the "invalid read", and that it tells you straight off that what you have is a stale pointer to deallocated memory ("0 bytes inside a block of size 40 free'd") -- and that it caught the problem at iteration 29 of the main loop.

Comment: Iteration 29 `-->` 29 is the 10th prime `-->` the memory was just expanded! Makes sense! Thanks very much for your experienced look at the problem. I will try using pointers to the array throughout the program functions and see if that fixes the runtime errors.

Comment: Right.  One of the things valgrind does for you is make sure `realloc` *always* invalidates the old pointer, instead of just *sometimes*.  You were probably getting crashes on prime 33791 because your C library was avoiding moving the block of memory until it absolutely had to, which happened at approximately 132kB allocated (33791 * 4 = 132 * 1024 - 4).

Comment: Pointers to the array for all the function calls was the solution. I changed the function signatures to contain a double de-referenced pointers (`uint32_t **primes`) and I changed the array access code to specifically de-reference the array prior to modification (`(*primes)[ (*count)++ ] = n`). That was the solution! No segmentation faults and `valgrind`'s analysis is clean!